# How to remove Adobe Creative Cloud icon from macOS menu bar?

Tags: macos, menu-bar, adobe

This Adobe Creative Cloud menu bar item is not making my life any better. How can I remove it permanently?

[image: Adobe Creative Cloud macOS menu bar icon]

- I tried right-clicking it. That did nothing
- Tried command-dragging it. That failed.

When I click the menu bar icon, it brings up a modal dialog for signing in to the Adobe Creative Cloud app. But it does not show an way to hide the menu bar icon.

Comment: You would need to look around adobe preferences and see if adobe has a option to get rid of it.

Comment: Why don't you just quit the app?

Comment: There is not quit option. I am not aware of any Adobe Preferences app.

Answer (score 1):

In v5.6.5.58, make the Creative Cloud app active by clicking on the icon in the menu bar. Select **Creative Cloud** > **Preferences** > **General**, then in the lower right-hand side of the window under **Settings** deselect **Launch Creative Cloud at login**.

This will keep the Creative Cloud icon out of the menu bar. I need to confirm this, but I don't think that your Adobe apps will be updated automatically. You will need to periodically launch the Creative Cloud app and check for updates manually.

[image: Screenshot of the Preferences window in Creative Cloud with the Launch at login option highlighted]

Comment: This toggle is already turned off. Still it appears in the menu bar

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bartender.app to manage your menu bar items.  It's a paid app with a free test period. 
https://www.macbartender.com/

[image]